# how to pass variable angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
  angular
  .module('MyApp')
  .controller('siteListSiteListController', siteListSiteListController)
  .controller('siteListSiteShowController', siteListSiteShowController);

siteListSiteListController.$inject = ['$scope', 'sites'];

function siteListSiteListController($scope, sites) {
    $scope.sites = sites.query();
    $scope.itemsByPage = 5;
}

siteListSiteShowController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'site', 'physicalLocationContacts'];

function siteListSiteShowController($scope, $routeParams, $location, site, physicalLocationContacts) {        
$scope.site = site.get({ GlobalLocId: $routeParams.GlobalLocId });        
$scope.physicalLocationContacts = physicalLocationContacts.query({ LocationId: 505 });        
  }
})();
```

$routeParams.GlobalLocId appears in the URL. the next line has a hard coded 505. How do I pass a value from site to physicalLocationContacts? The LocationId doesn't appear in the url.